# Reading BIOS variable contents/location from .bin or .rom

Tags: bios

For the past week or so, I've been [slowly] making progress on modding my BIOS (looking to eventually increase minimum RAM allocated to onboard video).

I've successfully flashed my BIOS to Insyde F.2D, and have extracted a bunch of files from the .exe file I used, including the BIOS .bin file.

I'm now looking for a way to read this file as to see where hidden variables exist (since HP locks down like... all advanced options). Since the BIOS is RSA signed, there's no modding + flashing the file directly—so I'll have to boot into an EFI shell and enter a command to change it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a good way to brick the PC, but if you do succeed you will make many HP PC owners very happy.

Comment: @Moab It *is* a great way to brick the PC, haha, but I've found a lot of positive results. Enough so that I'm fairly confident this will work; I just need to find exactly where the variable is stored on this particular laptop. :l